# WCF Secured Using Membership Provider, but getting certificate error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, security

I've created a custom membership provider and I am trying to use it to secure my WCF service. But, I am getting this error:

`The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.`

I don't want to use an x509 certificate. How can I get this working?

Here is my service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding1" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="UpdateService.UpdateService" behaviorConfiguration="ASPNETProviders">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding1"
      contract="UpdateService.IUpdateService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ASPNETProviders">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="myUpdateMembershipProvider"/>            
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior>          
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

## UPDATE

This blog post, [enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator.aspx), says:

`[When] you opt in for the UserName client credential type, WCF insists that your service must also reference a service certificate that contains a private key.`

I am going to host my service in IIS and plan to use SSL certificate in the web site for encrypting communication. Can I make WCF not insist that I reference a service certificate?

Comment: Thanks koregan. I think we were correcting that spelling mistake at the exact same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems that Microsoft really, really wants me to use a certificate.](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-use-clear-usernamepassword-with.html)

Someone developed a [Clear Username Binding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) for my situation, but I think I may just surrender and use a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to create a custom credential validator ? See this : http://nayyeri.net/custom-username-and-password-authentication-in-wcf-3-5